# Good Practice? Redefining Arrays to Change their Size

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working in Unity in C#, but this is a more general programming practice question.

```
dataType[] array = new dataType[x];

//Further down
dataType[] newArray = new dataType[array.Length + 1];

for (int i=0;i<array.Length;i++){
    newArray[i] = array[i];
}
```

Is this considered bad practice? Is it more/less efficient than just using an ArrayList?
I'm only performing this operation at the beginning of a level and then never again, so is it worth just working with ArrayLists?

Comment: why not just create an array with length `x+1` up front?

Comment: If there's one thing in the .net library that should be deprecated it's `ArrayList`'s.  If you need dynamic sizing use a `List`, or similar type of collection.  If not an `Array` will do.

Comment: No the idea is that I don't know how big the list will be. This would be performed repeatedly with different classes sort of calling in to let the array know it needs to grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is bad practice. If you expect your array size to change then use a List instead of an Array. List works just like an array in terms of indexing. To add new items to the List use Add(). You can even call ToArray() on the list to get an Array from it.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you come across a situation where you can't use a List and need to grow your Array, use Array.Resize() as shown below.

```
int[] array = new int[5];

Console.WriteLine(array.Length);

Array.Resize<int>(ref array, 20);

Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use dynamic data structures when you do not know the exact size of an array. List is a better option if you compare with ArrayList. ArrayList works only on objects whereas List<> make use of generics (which works on specific type or on object as well). This will help you create high performing and maintainable code.

Comment: An array is a data structure too.

Comment: Indeed, I meant dynamic data structure, I will correct it.